# Second loop ignores button press

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a reaction game with some light up arcade buttons on a Raspberry Pi running Python 2.7 and the first light/button push sequence works great, but after the second light is lit, the button push will not register in time.

```
def FastButtons(btn):
    btn.was_held = True
    Choice = random.choice([17, 22, 5, 24, 16])
    RedButton.when_pressed = FastPush
    BlueButton.when_pressed = FastPush
    YellowButton.when_pressed = FastPush
    GreenButton.when_pressed = FastPush
    WhiteButton.when_pressed = FastPush
    FastGo(Choice)

def FastGo(led):
    global FastButtonTime
    if led == 17:
        leds.Red.on()
        sleep(FastButtonTime)
        leds.Red.off()
    elif led == 22:
        leds.Blue.on()
        sleep(FastButtonTime)
        leds.Blue.off()
    elif led == 24:
        leds.Yellow.on()
        sleep(FastButtonTime)
        leds.Yellow.off()
    elif led == 5:
        leds.Green.on()
        sleep(FastButtonTime)
        leds.Green.off()
    elif led == 16:
        leds.White.on()
        sleep(FastButtonTime)
        leds.White.off()

def FastPush(btn):
    global GameOver
    global FastButtonTime
    if GreenButton.was_held:
        led = btn.pin.number
        if led  == 17:
                status = leds.Red.is_lit
        elif led == 22:
                status = leds.Blue.is_lit
        elif led == 24:
                status = leds.Yellow.is_lit
        elif led == 5:
                status = leds.Green.is_lit
        elif led == 16:
                status = leds.White.is_lit

        if status:
            print ("it's Active")
            if FastButtonTime > .3:
                FastButtonTime = FastButtonTime - .05
                print FastButtonTime
            leds.off()
            Winner = True
        else:
            print ("it's not active")
            Loser()
            GreenButton.was_held = False
            GameOver = True
            Winner = False
        if Winner:
            sleep(1)
            FastButtons(GreenButton)
```

On the second time through, it won't register the button press until the `sleep` in the `FastGo` definition is complete, thus causing the player to lose the game

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out why it wouldn't process the second time through after doing some research on how nested functions are executed, and because the `FastPush` calls `FastButtons`, it has to wait for that process to finish before it will accept another button push.

Because of this, I restructured all of my code to live in one function using how quickly the button was pushed as the verification of winning or losing instead of the state of the light.

If someone knows how to make it so that the light would turn off if the user takes too long without impeding the ability to push the button, that would be awesome! as it stands right now, it stays on until the button is pushed.

my new function looks like this for anyone interested

```
def FastButtons(btn):
        if not BlueButton.was_held and not WhiteButton.was_held:
                btn.was_held = True
                global Winner
                TimeAllowed = 1.5
                while True:
                        if not Winner:
                                blink(leds)
                                sleep(2)
                        led = random.choice([17, 22, 5, 24, 16])

                        if led == 17:
                                leds.Red.on()
                                start = time()
                                RedButton.wait_for_press()
                                stop = time()
                        elif led == 22:
                                leds.Blue.on()
                                start = time()
                                BlueButton.wait_for_press()
                                stop = time()
                        elif led == 24:
                                leds.Yellow.on()
                                start = time()
                                YellowButton.wait_for_press()
                                stop = time()
                        elif led == 5:
                                leds.Green.on()
                                start = time()
                                GreenButton.wait_for_press()
                                stop = time()
                        elif led == 16:
                                leds.White.on()
                                start = time()
                                WhiteButton.wait_for_press()
                                stop = time()
                        TotalTime = stop - start
                        print (TotalTime)

                        if TotalTime < TimeAllowed:
                                Winner = True
                                leds.off()
                                if TimeAllowed > .3:
                                        TimeAllowed = TimeAllowed - .05
                                RandomSleep = random.uniform(0.5, 3.5)
                                sleep (RandomSleep)
                        else:
                                FastLoser()
                                break

def FastLoser():
        global Winner
        Loser()
        GreenButton.was_held = False
        Winner = False
```